# How to display Posts in a Forum Web application using ASP .net C#

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a Forum Web Application using ASP .Net 3.5

I am facing issues in displaying Posts and replies under a selected question.
What display control shall I use in order to display the replies in separate boxes  with comment date and user id in them ?  (taking into account that Gridview is a Big NO)

Comment: thx for the reply.can u pls  share a link where I can get information on how to display a list using html tables,myself a novice in asp.It's difficult to find a tutorial on this.In php I could do this using directly by echoing Html table  and the result from database ..but where do i add that code here in ASP ? is it in the .aspx file ?

Answer (score 1):

I vote for [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx), seeing as how you want to display a list of replies.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a repeater and making your own html inside of it. It will be the most efficient way to get exactly the output you are looking for.

This link should get you started.
http://www.asp101.com/articles/john/repeater/default.asp

Comment: Thanks Kon and all2neat for ur suggestions. all2neat that link is a charm .. I like that :-). Let me try and work on it

Comment: Do yourself a favor and go listview.  Its like a repeater but with added functionality.